# How to copy the only Headers only from one datatable to another datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I know I can copy a complete datatable from on to another.
dtErrorLog = dtBaseDataTable.Copy();
But I need only the Headers from the original datatable to the new datatable.
How can I go about doing this

Comment: You can access to the `DataTable`'s columns via the instance property `Columns`. Just copy each column's property you want, from the original `Columns` collection to the new one. Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columns?view=net-6.0#remarks and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn?view=net-6.0#properties

Comment: A particular column can't belong to more than one datatable, so it really depends on what you need? If you just wanted the name and type, then that's easy enough, but if you want _all_ the properties you're going to have to write code to duplicate (or clone) the column

Comment: What if is did a copy then just did the following  for(int i = dtPerson.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr = dtPerson.Rows[i];
    if (dr["name"] == "Joe")
        dr.Delete();
}
dtPerson.AcceptChanges();

Comment: Have you tried… `dtErrorLog = dtBaseDataTable.Clone();` … ? …

Comment: I will try the clone.

Comment: Clone worked. Thank you